# Describe the kernel of the linear transform $T(A)=A+A^T$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

I'm working through an exercise in [Linear Algebra and its Applications, 4th ed. by D.C. Lay](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321399145).  The question asks:

Let $M_{2x2}$ be the vector space of all $2\times 2$ matrices, and define $T: M_{2x2} \to M_{2x2}$, where $A = \begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{bmatrix}$.  **Describe the kernel of the linear transform $T(A)=A+A^T$**

Not sure if this helps, but in an earlier part of the question, we discover that the the range of $T$ is the set of $B$ in $M_{2x2}$ with the property that $B^T=B$.

The **answer** is that the kernel of $T$ is $\{\begin{bmatrix} 0 & b \\ -b & 0 \end{bmatrix}: b \in real\}$

How can we arrive at this answer?

I tried to make $A = \begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ b & a \end{bmatrix}$, then calculate the reduced echelon form of the augmented matrix [$T(A)$ **0**].  However, I am not sure if this is the correct approach.

Comment: Use the fact that the diagonal entries are unchanged under transposition and the definition of the kernel of a linear map.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By definition of the kernel you want $T(A)=0$, where $0$ denotes the zero matrix.

So you want $A=-A^T$. Write this out and you'll see this forces $a=-a$, $d=-d$, and $b=-c$.

Comment: @Arnaldo Nascimento: I don't know what you're driving at. The kernel of a linear transformation is the preimage of the zero vector, yes.

Comment: @ArnaldoNascimento: no, you are confused. Asking for the vectors $v$ such that $T(A)v=0$ is asking for the kernel of $T(A)$, not the kernel of $T$. The "vectors" in the vector space $M_{2\times 2}$ are themselves matrices. That is why I pointed out that $0$ stands for the ($2\times 2$) zero *matrix*.

Comment: Totally right! I misread the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the help. So the textbook says the definition of Nul A is Ax=0.  Is this in fact equivalent to T(A)=0?

Comment: @jeffalltogether: that is the definition of the kernel of a *matrix* $A$. The kernel of a linear transformation $T$ is the set of objects in the domain of $T$ that get mapped to the zero vector. The action of Every linear transformation can be represented as multiplication by a matrix, but in your problem it is easier to work straight from the definition rather than find the matrix that represents $T$.

Comment: @symplectomorphic Thank you!  This problem makes sense to me now!

Answer (score 0):

So you need to show $T(A)=O$. That is, 
$$
 \begin{matrix}
    a & b\\
   c & d \\
  \end{matrix}
+ 
\begin{matrix}
 a & c\\
b & d\\
\end{matrix}
=\begin{matrix}
0 & 0\\
0 & 0 \\
\end{matrix}.
$$
The rest is algebra.

Comment: Thank you!  This helped me understand the the solution

Answer (score 0):

$$\ker T=\{A\in M_{2\times 2}:T(A)=0 \}=\{A\in M_{2\times 2}:A+A^T=0 \}$$ $$=\{A\in M_{2\times 2}:A^T=-A \}$$ So, $\ker T$ is the subspace of $M_{2\times 2}$ whose elements are the antisymmetric matrices.

Comment: Thank you!  This notation for the solution was useful!

Comment: Besides, the method and solution is valid not only for $M_{2\times 2}$ but in general for $M_{n\times n}$.